# Expo App can't find any OTA updates on production?

Tags: expo

I’m having an issue this morning: when I perform a `expo publish --release-channel staging`, all is working fine, I can see my app updating when I run it in the Expo app (`staging` version).

However, when I publish to `default`, I’m expecting to see my production bundle (released on the stores) to check for (OTA) updates and well, updates. After several updates this way, working fine, it seems like my production app doesn’t see the new OTA update that I published on `default`.

I checked my app SDK version, I’m using Expo 37 on staging and production.

When I check my app’s builds on expo.io, I don’t see any builds done today.

I don’t see what is going wrong and what I can do to debug that…

Any ideas?

*Here's how I'm checking for OTA updates (just double checking version and displaying a modal):*

```
Updates.checkForUpdateAsync().then(update => {
  if(update.isAvailable && (Constants.manifest.revisionId !== update.manifest.revisionId)) {
    setUpdateObj(update);
    Updates.fetchUpdateAsync().then(response => {
      setModalAppUpdateOpened(true);
    }) ;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, after 6 hours, my app is seeing the OTA updates poping up in my production bundle, I guess it's just an unusual delay on Expo service.

Comment: this is an actual issue I've been encountering lately. Some release channels work and some don't. No idea what is going on with expo publishing.